# Неэффективный алгоритм: возможно ли оптимизировать?

Tags: excel, vba, алгоритм, visual-basic

Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, адекватный ли алгоритм у меня получился?
Я считаю, что его можно усовершенствовать или как минимум оптимизировать(

Думала в сторону regexp, но идеи как его сюда прикрутить - не появилось(

Суть: в папке по заданному адресу есть файлы, нужно найти текущий (номер соответствует счётчику более высокого цикла - i). Проблема в том, что перед этим i может стоять ещё один, два или три нолика. И в зависимости от этого разные последствия происходят)

```
    If (i < 10 And Dir$(folderAdress$ + "TNV - 000" & i & "-1.xls") <> "" And nextsl = True) Then
        Workbooks.Open folderAdress$ & "TNV - 000" & i & "-1.xls"
        outTNVfilename = "ТНВ - 000" & i & "-1.xls"
        tk = "/1"
        nextsl = False
        u = i
    ElseIf (i < 10 And Dir$(folderAdress$ + "TNV - 000" & u & "-2.xls") <> "" And nextsl = False) Then
        Workbooks.Open folderAdress$ & "TNV - 000" & u & "-2.xls"
        outTNVfilename = "ТНВ - 000" & u & "-2.xls"
        tk = "/2"
        nextsl = True
        i = u
    ElseIf (i < 10 And Dir$(folderAdress$ + "TNV - 000" & i & ".xls") <> "") Then
        Workbooks.Open folderAdress$ & "TNV - 000" & i & ".xls"
        outTNVfilename = "ТНВ - 000" & i & ".xls"
        tk = ""

    ElseIf (i > 9 And i < 100 And Dir$(folderAdress$ + "TNV - 00" & i & "-1.xls") <> "" And nextsl = True) Then
        Workbooks.Open folderAdress$ & "TNV - 00" & i & "-1.xls"
        outTNVfilename = "ТНВ - 00" & i & "-1.xls"
        tk = "/1"
        nextsl = False
        u = i
    ElseIf (i > 9 And i < 100 And Dir$(folderAdress$ + "TNV - 00" & u & "-2.xls") <> "" And nextsl = False) Then
        Workbooks.Open folderAdress$ & "TNV - 00" & u & "-2.xls"
        outTNVfilename = "ТНВ - 00" & u & "-2.xls"
        tk = "/2"
        nextsl = True
        i = u
    ElseIf (i > 9 And i < 100 And Dir$(folderAdress$ + "TNV - 00" & i & ".xls") <> "") Then
        Workbooks.Open folderAdress$ & "TNV - 00" & i & ".xls"
        outTNVfilename = "ТНВ - 00" & i & ".xls"
        tk = ""

    ElseIf (i > 99 And i < 1000 And Dir$(folderAdress$ + "TNV - 0" & i & "-1.xls") <> "" And nextsl = True) Then
        Workbooks.Open folderAdress$ & "TNV - 0" & i & "-1.xls"
        outTNVfilename = "ТНВ - 0" & i & "-1.xls"
        tk = "/1"
        nextsl = False
        u = i
    ElseIf (i > 99 And i < 1000 And Dir$(folderAdress$ + "TNV - 0" & u & "-2.xls") <> "" And nextsl = False) Then
        Workbooks.Open folderAdress$ & "TNV - 0" & u & "-2.xls"
        outTNVfilename = "ТНВ - 0" & u & "-2.xls"
        tk = "/2"
        nextsl = True
        i = u
    ElseIf (i > 99 And i < 1000 And Dir$(folderAdress$ + "TNV - 0" & i & ".xls") <> "") Then
        Workbooks.Open folderAdress$ & "TNV - 0" & i & ".xls"
        outTNVfilename = "ТНВ - 0" & i & ".xls"
        tk = ""
    End If
```

Comment: Так: 01,001,0001?

Answer (score 2):

Надо разбить на меньшие функции, чтобы код стал обозримым. Проблема в вашем коде скорее в многочисленных повторах и связанной с этим возможности неконсистентного поведения. Псевдокод:

```
sub getBaseFilename(i)
    dim r$ as string
    r$ = Str$(i)
    while (len(r$) < 4)
        r$ = "0" & r$
    return "TNV - " & r$

sub exists(name$)
    return Dir$(folderAdress$ & name$) <> ""

sub process(i)
    found = False
    baseName$ = getBaseFilename(i)
    name$ = baseName$ & "-1.xls"
    if (exists(name$))
        tk = "/1"
        nextsl = False
        u = i

    if (not found)
        name$ = baseName$ & "-2.xls"
        if (exists(name$))
            tk = "/2"
            nextsl = True
            i = u
            found = True

    if (not found)
        name$ = baseName$ & ".xls"
        if (exists(name$))
            tk = "/2"
            found = True

    if (found)
        outTNVfilename = name$
        Workbooks.Open folderAdress$ & name$
```